# Is reading a bool atomic and how many cycles it takes

Tags: c++

is reading a bool an atomic action?

```
if (value != true)//here I'm reading bool, then I'm comparing it to the value I'm interested in.
```

Also, how many processor cycles it takes to read it?

Comment: What does "reading a bool" mean? Reading from where? Disk, memory, input, wall, book?

Comment: I store all my bool's in the cloud.

Comment: @Konrad: it's difficult to guess, considering that (for example) a `bool` variable might easily be located either in memory or on disk (swap file) at the point you read it. Beyond that, it's just a question of how far you want to stretch the point that the answer to the question, especially the part about cycle count, is a massive "it depends".

Comment: @Steve I concede the swap file point, but no more. The context is atomic reads, this is nomenclature normally reserved for main memory operations. And swap files should *never* influence guarantees of atomicity, though they of course influence timing – but this is something that a complete answer should address anyway.

Comment: @Konrad: before the example code was added, I don't think it would be a big stretch to think that the question conceivably might mean, "is `operator>>(istream &, bool &)` thread-safe?". OK, so there are politer ways to request clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is reading a bool an atomic action?

The C++ standard doesn't enforce any guarantees.

> how many processor cycles it takes to read it?

It depends on the processor, and it depends on where it's being read from (disk swap vs. main memory vs. cache vs. register).

Comment: Unless it's `std::atomic_flag` in C++11 in which case the first part changes

Comment: @awoodland: Indeed. But I'm assuming that the OP means `bool`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Will accept when the time comes.

Comment: @Evgeni: `volatile` has nothing to do with atomicity; it just prevents the compiler from adding, removing or rearranging accesses to variables.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sorry, my mind grouped atomicity and not-storing-in-cache together...

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a real world example, consider this code:

```
void f(bool x)
{
    if (x == true) x++;
}
```

If compiled with `g++ -S`, it gives this output:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  _Z1fb
    .type   _Z1fb, @function
_Z1fb:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, %eax
    movb    %al, -4(%rbp)
    cmpb    $0, -4(%rbp)
    je  .L1
    movb    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z1fb, .-_Z1fb
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

If, before the `cmpb    $0, -4(%rbp)` instruction, another thread changes the value of `rbp`, than the result of the comparison will be undefined.